# converting Week/year to date power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a column that contains Week/year and I want to convert it to dd/mm/yyyy

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Note : I used this but it didn't work

```
  let
Source = {Number.From(#date(YourYear,01,01))..Number.From(#date(YourYear,12,31))},
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type date}}),
WeekColumn = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Week", each Date.WeekOfYear([Column1])),
StartOfWeek = Table.AddColumn(WeekColumn, "StartOfWeek", each Date.StartOfWeek([Column1])),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(StartOfWeek, each [Week] >= List.Min(YourWeekList) and [Week] <= List.Min(YourWeekList))
in
#"Filtered Rows1"
```

Comment: Hello, have you seen [this post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/convert-week-number-into-data/td-p/88227) ? If so, why didn't it work ? Thanks !

Comment: Yes I did, It gives a wrong value

Comment: Why is the value wrong ? Is it a wrong day in the week or a different week altogether ?

Comment: @reportgunner It shows me a table but I want to have a column so I can see the conversion of each row can you help me with that?

Comment: I did't with this : ndate = DATE([year],1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE([year],1,3))+[week]*7

Comment: can you post a sample of your data and your desired outcome?